# Warning on running Google Chrome 59 headless mode

Tags: google-chrome, suppress-warnings, headless-browser

I want to use Google Chrome headless mode.

I type this.

```
google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --dump-dom --no-sandbox http://google.com
```

and it always show warning in the first output like below.

```
[0722/222841.700788:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(293)] Multiple instances of AudioManager detected
[0722/222841.700844:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(254)] Multiple instances of AudioManager detected
```

What causing that? I want to have clean output of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try read this tutorial 
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome
It can depends from your OS. Mac and Windows have some specific.
As for now, i can run your command without any problem on MacOS.